# PowerShell and CSV: Stop CSV from turning text data into Scientific Notation

Tags: powershell, csv, formatting, scientific-notation

I have a CSV column with alpha numerical combinations in a column.
I am later going to use this csv file in a PowerShell script by importing the data.

Examples: 1A01, 1C66, 1E53.
Now before putting these values in, I made sure to format the column as text.
Now at first it works. I input the data, save. I test in PowerShell to import it and
all data shows up valid including 1E53. But lets say I edit the file again later to add data and then save and close. I re-import into PowerShell and 1E53 comes in as 1.00E+53. How can I prevent this permanently? Note that the column is filled with codes and there are lots of #E##.

Comment: PowerShell using `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` doesn't alter the values. I quess you are opening the csv files in Excel and there the conversion happens. If you have a CSV file like that and do not want Excel to mess up your field format, prefix these field values with a TAB character (so change each value in that column with ``$value = "`t$value"``)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented:

You will probably load the csv from file:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path 'X:\original.csv' -UseCulture
```

The code below uses a dummy csv in a Here-String here:

```
$csv = @'
"Column1","Column2","ValueThatMatters"
"Something","SomethingElse","1E53"
"AnotherItem","Whatever","4E12"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

# in order to make Excel see the values as Text and not convert them into scientific numbers
$csv | ForEach-Object {
    # add a TAB character in front of the values in the column
    $_.ValueThatMatters = "`t{0}" -f $_.ValueThatMatters
}
$csv | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\ExcelFriendly.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. During the foreach it says my column cannot be found on this object.

Comment: @MilanPatel Of course.. i just made up an example since you didn't show any of your csv file.. Change the name of the field from `ValueThatMatters` to whatever is the **real** name in your file

Comment: That is what I did =), 
and it still doesn't work. 
Also, i am going to go through the data to comparisons so lets say i do add tab to 1E53. Later if i try a comparison to search for it, 1E53 wont equal to tab1E53. Which is an issue.

Comment: @MilanPatel Well.. for me it works: ``(Import-Csv D:\Test\blah.csv)[0].ValueThatMatters -eq "`t1E53"`` happily returns True. You can also use `Trim()` to remove the added whitespace (the tab) so you can compare with the original value: `(Import-Csv D:\Test\blah.csv)[0].ValueThatMatters.Trim() -eq "1E53"`. The TAB-thing is only needed for when you want to open a CSV file with values like that in Excel by double-clicking it. Excell is very eager to 'interpret/convert' anything it thinks _can_ be converted, whether you like it or not..

Comment: @MilanPatel The only other way is to open the csv from inside a new Excel file and use its menu `Data --> From Text`. Then if you go through the wizard you can tell it NOT to convert the values but regard your column as text.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is not with PowerShell, its with Excel. For a demonstration, take `1E53` and enter it into Excel and then save that excel file as a CSV file. You will see that the value is now changed to `1.00E+53`.

How to fix this?

There are a few ways of disabling scientific notation:

https://superuser.com/questions/452832/turn-off-scientific-notation-in-excel
https://www.logicbroker.com/excel-scientific-notation-disable-prevent/

I hope some of them work for you.

I think you can rename the file to .txt instead of .csv and excel may treat it differently.

Good Luck

Comment: Those methods in your link are things I have tried and it doesn't solve the big issue that if I go to edit the csv file, it resets and will convert those codes to scientific notation. For now I have to keep updating the excel file and make a fresh csv.

Also this "I think you can rename the file to .txt instead of .csv and excel may treat it differently." <-- not sure how that solves my issue. Can you expand on it?

Comment: When you open a txt file in Excel, it gives you an option to change the format of the cells and you can select text.