# Convert Scientific notation to decimal in .csv with Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, csv, decimal, scientific-notation

I'm trying to write a Powershell script that converts all scientific notations in a csv file to decimal.

For that :

```
$list = Import-CSV -Path .\this.csv -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8
foreach($col in $list){
        $col.price = $col.price -as [double]
        Write-Output $col.price
}
```

But the results of this do not change the output strings.

Any solution ?

Thx.
Etienne

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell and CSV: Stop CSV from turning text data into Scientific Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68954459/powershell-and-csv-stop-csv-from-turning-text-data-into-scientific-notation)

Comment: @Vivere I've already tried it and it doesn't return any value. I think it's due to the type of my value which is not a string... When I change my code to **$col.price = "`t$col.price" -as [string]** the result is **@{price=1,23456789012346E+026}.price**

Comment: Replace the `,` with `.`: `$col.price.Replace(',','.') -as [double]` (although you probably want a `[decimal]` or a `[bigint]` rather than a `[double]`)

Comment: Please share an example

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, thanks for your answer. That works for E+28 numbers but not bigger than this and I work on very large numbers. Thx also for the [decimal] indication.

Comment: @An-dir I can't post pictures... But the code I wrote before represent my problem. I just can't post a real rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this :

```
foreach($col in $list){
            $col.price = $col.price.Replace(',','.')
            $col.price = $col.price.Replace(' ','') -as [decimal]
            Write-Output $col.price
}
```

and it works :D

Answer (score 0):

Here I wrote an example CSV as there was no example provided

```
"Name;Price
1;123.4E+03
2;1.666E-08" | Out-File this.csv
```

This is the new version of your code that gets the CSV
Then for the output I selected 2 columns (Name,Price) and redefined what the content of price should be.

```
$list = Import-CSV -Path .\this.csv -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8
$list | Select-Object Name,@{Name="Price";expression={$_.Price -as [Decimal]}}
```

The output looks like that:

```
Name         Price
----         -----
1           123400
2    0,00000001666
```

If it does not work with your CSV, then please share an example.